# MEANJS HashBang Removal

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, meanjs

I'm using [MEANJS](http://meanjs.org) and I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the `#!` from the urls and still have Express pick up the urls? I can remove `#!` from the urls in angular but then Express doesn't pick up the urls and has issues when using the social sign up featurs that come with the framework.

Is the utopia solution an option with the frame or it is just something that comes with the package?

Comment: have you tried enabling Html5 mode?

Comment: @FelipeSkinner yeah I've enabled that in Angularjs but none of the Express routes work after enabling it.

Comment: Might be an old question, but did you take a look at meanjs 0.4.0? It's not yet released but they are using html5mode without the hashbang mode. Maybe it's worth to check the differences in angular/express routing in both 0.3.0 and 0.4.0 and apply them to your project.

Comment: @user3632710 hey I have not looked at it yet. I will definitely check out the repo for 0.4 and see if it holds any answers. thanks for the suggestion